# Unable to load dynamic library 'curl.so'

Tags: php, macos, curl, openssl, homebrew

I have a PHP package, when I run the package I get following error:

```
make: [unit] Error 1 (ignored)
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'curl.so' (tried: /php/20121212/curl.so (dlopen(/php/20121212/curl.so, 0x0009): dlopen(): file not found: /php/20121212/curl.so), /php/20121212/curl.so.so (dlopen(/php/20121212/curl.so.so, 0x0009): dlopen(): file not found: /php/20121212/curl.so.so)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'openssl.so' (tried: /php/20121212/openssl.so (dlopen(/php/20121212/openssl.so, 0x0009): dlopen(): file not found: /php/20121212/openssl.so), /php/20121212/openssl.so.so (dlopen(/php/20121212/openssl.so.so, 0x0009): dlopen(): file not found: /php/20121212/openssl.so.so)) in Unknown on line 0
```

I have tried upgrading Curl by `brew update curl` and nothing seems to have an affect. And I have no context on openssl.so too. Below is my PHP version.

```
php -v                                                                                             ✔  13:26:31
PHP 7.3.11 (cli) (built: Jun  5 2020 23:50:40) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.3.11, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
```

How can I handle those two dynamic library imports?

Comment: It seems the version you installed (7.3) is not the one being used for running your scripts (i.e. php executables are different for when its ran with make, and via console). PHP with date 20121212 points to php version 5.6.

Comment: Okay, So I would need to install 5.6 then? Wouldn't it be the other way around?

Comment: If you do not have any scripts that depend on version 5.6 then yes, go ahead and upgrade your system' PHP version. Be mindful of it as these versions, obviously, might not be 100% compatible.

Comment: Hey this doesn't seems to work.
Where do I have to update the PHP running version?